# Should all back-end servers have the same cache content when we use load balancing?

Tags: caching, load-balancing

Suppose that we have a load balancing with multiple back-end servers. Each back-end server has a cache that contains information about users to avoid querying database extensively. There are a very large number of users in the system. Does the caches of these servers need to have the same content or each server can have a different cache that contains the information of different users? Is this a good practice?

For example,  we use 2 back-end servers. The 1st server only process request about users having even user_id and therefore its cache contains only users with even id. In parallel, the 2nd server only process request about users having odd user_id and therefore its cache contains only users with odd id. Is this a good practice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on what network level you do load balancing. If you use l7 load balancer with cookie persistence - you can redirect all user requests with even user_id to 1st server and all user request with odd user_id to 2nd server - therefore you do not need to cache odd user_id on 1st server and even user_id on 2nd server. I do not think that caching in back-end is good practice, in my opinion it is better to use in-memory database (memcached, redis, tarantool etc) for this purpose